# keep only the value under certain conditions

Tags: python, dataframe, sorting

PANDAS - Python

in a column of a dataframe how can I keep only the values that are of a certain type (for example less than 50)? I don't want a true / false answer but the value

this is what I thought so far

```py
for i in b['prod_price']<500:
  c=b['prod_price']

print (c)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to index the original dataframe with the values you obtain from the boolean statement. Moreover, it is almost never a good idea to use for loops with dataframes, as they are already vectorized:

```py
c = b[b['prod_price'] < 500]
```

Comment: thank's but it is not working.... stil getting "true" in the column of the price and not the actual price

Comment: It would be best if you share the data so we can reproduce the issue.

Comment: sorry, don't know how to do it because it's an online exercise...but thank's